# Upgrade 14.04 to 16.04 failed

Tags: 14.04

When trying this upgrade on a windows partition I get this failure

- Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
- Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu
- Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu

I presume it is the last problem, but have tried suggestions in various questions to no avail.

E.g. I have run

> sudo apt-get install -f

to fix broken packages, but still have the problem.

Any more suggestions?

Update 29/5/2017

From a post indicating unofficial packages can be found with this,

```
apt-show-versions | grep 'No available version'
```

showed  package called scenebuilder, and I removed in synaptic.

And I unchecked a ros thing in Software and Updates -> Other
did a `sudo apt-get update` and tried to upgrade again, but still get the same error message,

> Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu

Would really appreciate some help on this, I have spent days on it and not getting anywhere. Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: Your question does not provide any details on a 'failure'. Please edit your question to clearly explain the problem.

Comment: And what does a "Windows partition" have to do with Ubuntu upgrades?

Comment: @user535733 The failure error is in the post. Were you looking for something else?

Comment: @MichaelBay it is possible to install Ubuntu on part of a windows operating system, known as a "partition". That is the context of my upgrade.

Comment: Sorry but no and no. You posted a vague "when trying this upgrade..." that means nothing and says nothing where it would be expected a description of the actual process and an error message eventually. Partitions are not "part of Windows" (or any other OS), Windows and any other OS *lives* on one or more partitions. Now, although Ubuntu can r/w NTFS and FAT partitions, typical of Windows, it can't be installed, hence my question about what that has to do with whatever you're trying to do. And why is this so eerily similar to a question of yours almost 6 months ago?

Comment: This: https://askubuntu.com/questions/859522/failure-to-upgrade-14-04-to-16-04 Please start by describing what you're really doing and what happens, error messages, etc. Also please don't assume other users are dumb.

Comment: Oh, THAT upgrade error message. Your formatting mislead me. That's easy: You have unwisely installed non-Ubuntu software (from a non-Ubuntu source) that is creating a logical paradox. The paradox is blocking the release-upgrade. Uninstall ALL non-Ubuntu software from ALL non-Ubuntu sources. And disable or delete those non-Ubuntu sources. That will remove the paradox, and prevent it from returning. Then apt will be able to calculate the release-upgrade. After the successful release-upgrade, feel free to re-install whatever non-Ubuntu software you wish from whatever source you wish.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks. How can I find what are  non-Ubuntu software packages?

Comment: @PerceptualRobotics that's a different question, and already answered- search for it.

Comment: @user535733 well that's probably fine if you know what question to ask, but I spent an hour last night searching for an answer, but couldn't find it. What question should I be asking?

Comment: ppa-purge is a useful tool for removing this software. However it is easier to back up your data and install fresh.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks. Do you mean that I need to run ppa-purge for ros, in addition to what I have already done? Could you point me to the procedure for backup, install, recovery please?